# How do I write a script that gives back integers 1 through 10?

Tags: loops

Super new to python. Working on a short script that writes numbers 1-10.
Tried out:

```
x = 0
if x < 11:
    x + 1
else:
    print('done')
```

---

My logic is
x is set to int 0
adds one until x=11 and then prints "done"

Would it be more effective using a while statement instead?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you wrote is not a loop. Maybe you could start [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp)?

Comment: @evilmandarine

I eventually figured a way after some tinkering. Thank you for the web source though, I will practice on it as I have yet to understand the basics.

x = 0
while x != 10:
    x = x + 1
    print(x)

My logic is x equals 0 while x is not equal to 10, x will be set to x + 1 print the new x and continue until x = 10. Not a loop either but a while statement. Thank you again for the help.

Comment: ...like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp)? A `while` loop is also a loop. Your logic is correct, but I think you should follow a basic programming language tutorial in Python (or any language you want). Loops exist in most languages.